# Integrate CLion with conan test

Tags: clion, conan

I followed the example https://github.com/lasote/conan-gtest-example to add GTest to my project via conan. Moreoever I followed these instructions https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/ide/clion.html to set up conan within CLion. 
The two samples work as expected. But I cannot get CLion pick up the files under "test_package" when I follow both instructions. How can I set up CLion correctly to work with my test_package by using conan?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using that plugin.

The Clion plugin is able to run `conan install` under the hood.
You can take a look on Clion's [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/05/getting-started-with-the-conan-clion-plugin/) about how to integrate both tools.
The idea is creating a plugin to solve your dependencies for C++ project, not a shortcut when creating Conan packages.

If you want to build that package and testing it, you should run:

```
conan create . soccertrash/testing
```

The command above will export, install, build and test your package. To learn more about, you can read the docs [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html#creating-and-testing-packages).

To request a new feature, as your mentioned before, you can open a new request for Conan team [here](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-clion-plugin).

Regards!